# Winding number and Cauchy integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis

In Alfors's text, the following theorem is introduced. 
In here, I can't figure out one statement.

[image]

As $f$ has finitely many zeros on $D$, each zero $z_i$ has an open neighborhood 
$N_{z_i}$ such that $g(z_i)\neq0$ and $f=(z-z_i)^p g$ on $N_{z_i}$ where $p$ is a positive integer. But, this is just local property. How can I get the global non-vanishing function $g$ on $D$?

Comment: $z_1, \cdots, z_n$ are the **complete list** of zeros of $f$ in $D$.

Comment: Then any additional zero that comes from $g$ will be an additional zero of $f$.

Comment: @i707107 / I got a big hint from your comment and copper.hat's answer . Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f(z_0) = 0$ then the power series expansion shows that $f(z) = (z-z_0) g(z) $, where $g(z) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k (z-z_0)^{k-1} $ locally and since $z \mapsto {1 \over z-z_0} f(z)=g(z)$ is
analytic for $z \neq z_0$ we see that $g$ is analytic on $D$.

Note that the zeros of $g$ are also zeros of $f$, hence finite in number.

Repeat this (on the corresponding $g$) for each $z_k$ until all the zeros in $D$ are exhausted.

Comment: I got a big hint from your answer and i707107's comment. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Let $y$ be a zero of $f$, of order $m$. Let g(z) be defined as follows : 
$$
g(z) = \begin{cases}
(z-y)^{-m}f(z) \ \ \ \ \ z \neq y \\
\frac{1}{n!} f^{(n)}(y) \quad \quad \ \ \ \ \ z = y
\end{cases}
$$ 
I'll leave it to you to check that $g$ is non-zero on $D$, and is holomorphic on $D$. Now, you can inductively extend this to other zeros.

Comment: I think you consider the multiplicity of each zero for the general case. Thank you :)

Comment: Correct, @Chriskim